# Use Mailchimp link tracking in non-Mailchimp-generated email?

Tags: mailchimp

I have a list of Mailchimp subscribers. I would like to send about 100 of them a "your account is ready!" email and check the performance of the email.

For various technical reasons, I need to send this outside Mailchimp (the email needs to include their account username, so it has to be generated from our database).

Is there a way I can use Mailchimp performance tracking in this email? I would like to know which of them open the email and which of them click on the link.

Comment: That sounds like a transactional email instead of a newsletter.   Are you sending it with Mandrill, Mailchimp's transactional product?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller no, but clearly I should be! Currently I'm just using a node script. Mandrill looks great, thanks for the tip.